# How to create shaped wordclouds with individual links which are clickable?

Tags: word-cloud

A month or so ago, on wolfram.com, there was a wordcloud which had multipe clickable links. I wanted to make a wordcloud which is in the shape of an american flag that has clickable links. So when a word below is clicked, it should be taken to the corresponding wikipedia link

`governance, administration, politics, democracy, governing, state, judiciary, authorities, regime, government, legislature, executive, country, federal, aristocracy, policy, ministry, bureaucracy, party, constitutional, monarchy, constitution, anarchism, military, privatization, states, minimalist, law, republic, oligarchy, anarchy, office, sovereignty, congress, local, papacy, empire, political, civilization, organization, federal, misrule, socialism, organization, manifesto, dictatorship, influence, official, bond, mandate, legislation, tyrant, parliament, authority, monarchy, legislative, power, economics, nation, civil, liberalism, governor, lawmakers, policies, commission, opposition, foreign, reforms, public, coalition, cabinet, elections, agencies, philosophy, election, rule`

Comment: does this work: `links= Hyperlink[#, "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" <> #] & /@ words; WordCloud[links]` where `words = ToString/@yourlist`?

Comment: @kglr How would i shape that into a flag?

Comment: maybe `flag= Binarize@ CountryData["US", "Flag"] ; WordCloud[links, flag] `?